# Change Image SRC before page loads original src

Tags: jquery, volusion

right now I am using the following JQuery code to change all of the image SRCs on a page to access my other image server which has a higher bandwidth limit.

```
$.each($("img"), function( index, value ) {
    srcValue = "http://different-server.com/" + $(this).attr("src")
    $(this).attr("src", srcValue)
});
```

So

```
src="v/image1.jpg"
src="v/image2.jpg"
src="v/image2.jpg"
```

Would become:

```
src="http://different-server.com/v/image1.jpg"
src="http://different-server.com/v/image2.jpg"
src="http://different-server.com/v/image3.jpg"
```

A client is using Volusion for their shopping cart. They are forced to host their shopping cart on Volusion's servers which only allows 3gb of Bandwidth usage per month and they charge a lot for going over.

The cart is built in ASP but I have no access to the ASP pages but only to template files and we are not allowed to link product images to an external source.

I was successfully able to download the image files for the shopping cart products and host them on another host with no bandwidth limit but I feel that this code changes the src AFTER the browser loads the original image SRCs so in the end, the bandwidth usage issue is still present.

The client is not willing to switch to a self-hosted option so I am left to figure out a solution to reduce their bandwidth usage as much as possible so that they are not overcharged in the future.

Is there anything more I can do to force the image srcs to be changed before the page loads since I only have access to editing template files?

Thank you.

Comment: Why don't you leave the `src` empty in the initial HTML, and fill it in with JS.

Comment: Unfortunately, it is Volusion's limitations that stop me from doing that. Otherwise, that would be a good idea. We are only given one html file to edit the template. The only way to add images onto a cart's page is to go through their GUI and upload images to their server. So that is why I am left to try dirtier tactics.

Answer (score 1):

Each Volusion product has two fields where you can specify the URL, Photo URL Small and Photo URL Large. This can point to an internal or external location for the product images.

Answer (score 0):

From client-side Javascript, you cannot change an `img.src` in the HTML of the page before the browser starts to load it.  You are not going to be able to fix your problem from client-side Javascript alone.

The reason for this is that you can't modify a DOM object with Javascript until it has been parsed by the browser and has become part of the DOM and by the time that has completed, the browser may have already started to load the image from its original URL.  So, you're stuck.  You can't get to it with Javascript until it has already started to load which means your low bandwidth server has already seen the request before you could change the URL.

The real solution here (which I presume you know) is to change the HTML of the page to fix the URLs.  Or, if you wanted the hostname for the images to be set via Javascript, then you could change the img tags to use a `data-src` property and no `src` property and then you could use Javascript to set the `src` property to what you wanted.  This would work because when the images have no `src` property, the browser can parse the `<img>` tag, but won't start loading anything (since there is no `src` property).

Server-side proxies configured to rewrite the images URLs could also be used.

Comment: I have an idea of where you are going with this! The issue is, with editing the HTML, we can only really edit the header, menu, footer, etc. but not the content area. In the template file, there is an empty div with the class "content_area" and all of the page content gets thrown in there with ASP (which I unfortunately cannot access). I can't really edit any of html for how the images are displayed on the page since that falls into content that is thrown into the "content_area" div.  Can I work around that somehow?

Comment: @AndrewMRiv - I know you don't want this to be the answer, but "no" there is no client-side work-around.  You can rewrite the image URLs with JS and "hope" that it lessens the bandwidth used because maybe some browsers will stop loading images that it had already started, now that the source URL has been changed.  But frankly, that behavior will vary from browser to browser (you'd have to test with uncached images to see if it does any good), but it certainly won't prevent all usage from the low bandwidth server and honestly I have no idea if it would even reduce the bandwidth usage.

Comment: @AndrewMRiv - FYI, there are likely legitimate security reasons why the provider does not want externally loaded resources in the cart.  There are not good reasons for restricting the bandwidth usage to such a low number - there are better providers that will not do that or will have a much more reasonable bandwidth charge.

Comment: I appreciate your help and honesty. I figured that that would ultimately be the answer. I will do that and "hope" that at least some browsers somehow follow that.  Other than that, I'll just try to host as many of the CSS and JS files on the third party source as well as template images such as logos, social media icons, etc.   Thank you again.